# FPDM cant print € when Merge(true)

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm trying to print **€** symbol on PDF forms with `Merge(true)` but it is shown **'â‡¬'** instead but its printed correctly when `Merge(false)`.

Link to library [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) and I'm using PHP 8.2.5.

I tried to fix it by using `utf8_decode` but it shows **'?'** and by changing second parameter in FPDM Load method but there is no difference.

I'm using Arial font.

Example code:

```
$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$fields["name"] = 20.5 . "€"; //outputs 20.5€
$pdf->Load($fields, true);
$pdf->Merge(false);
$pdf->Output("D", "name.pdf");
return $pdf;
```

Example code2:

```
$pdf = new FPDM('template.pdf');
$fields["name"] = 20.5 . "€"; //outputs 20.5â‡¬
$pdf->Load($fields, true);
$pdf->Merge(true);
$pdf->Output("D", "name.pdf");
return $pdf;
```

Tried to use `chr(128)` instead, but doesn't show anyway.

Comment: The FPDM library does not support UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Are your PHP file containing the current code saved with the **UTF-8** character encoding? Also I think you must use the **utf8_encode** function, not the decode one

Comment: utf8_encode() is decrepated! https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode Same for utf8_decode().

Comment: would there be anyway to make it UTF-8 compatible or just print that € symbol, as it is the only character that doesnt seems to work?